Why does my celery task status is SUCCESS although it raised an error?
I am trying to use celery but i faced a problem.
I checked in celery_taskmeta table in database and I saw the task status is SUCCESS, but it raise an Error in the log.
this is my celery code:
@celery.task(name="celery_sample", bind=True, track_started=True)
def celery_sample_task(self, input_data: dict):

    try:
        celery_sample = CelerySampleService()
        ret = celery_sample .sample_function(input_data)
        result = ret['result']

        save_path = './services/resul/'
        file_name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
        full_file_path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name + '.txt')
        file = open(full_file_path, 'w')
        file.write(result)
        file.close()
        return full_file_path
    
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

I think celery status is always SUCCESS if I use try...except?
Any idea?

Well, yeah… you're catching any and all errors and just return a string in either case. Celery can't magically know whether an error happened inside your task during execution. All it knows is whether your task raises an exception or not. And since you don't let it raise an exception, it won't.

Yes. I tried adding "raise" and it works. thank you

as we said, you can remove your try-except .But did you understand why?

yes. I tried it too and I removed try-except

You are managing the exception, if you want to propagate it.
Change this
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)

To
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(e)

Or just remove your try-except

There usually isn't a compelling reason to create and raise a new exception. That should just be raise e, which can be shortened to raise. Or, as you say, just getting rid of the entire try..except to begin with.

you are right, i just followed him code. I used to do for custom error like: raise Exception("My custom error message")

Sure, there are cases where converting one exception type into a different one makes sense. But this doesn't seem to be one of those cases.

I tried adding raise and it worked. thank you!
